# Scrollable side bar with bootstrap fluid layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, overflow

I need some help with this, i want to have a sidebar and a content div using bootstrap fluid layout but i cant make the sidebar to be scrollable and the content div not. I already tried using overflow:hidden; on body and applying overflow:auto on the sidebar div but it doesnt works, what am i missing?
Heres my scss code:

```
  #main-container{
       margin-left:0;
       margin-top:60px;
       padding:0px;
   .span3{
        background-color:white;
        ul{
        margin: 0;

        li#song{
            background-image: url($images+'chevron.png');
            background-position: right center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-color:white;
            color: #666;
            border-top: 1px solid #B4B4B4;
            list-style-type: none;
            padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
             }
           }
         }
       }

    .maxheight{
     height:100%;
    }

    .no-overflow{
   overflow-y:hidden;
     }

   .scrollable{
   height:100%;
   overflow-x:hidden;
    }
```

Here is the example code, the left div is what i want to scroll: http://jsfiddle.net/xYDRg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set height for that div:

```
#lista-canciones{
    height: 350px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xYDRg/1/

Comment: I was setting height:100% but i think it doesnt work with, i have to put it in pixels. Thanks man!